# Costs of PCI Compliance?

Tags: php, credit-card, pci-dss, pci-compliance

We're developing a new piece of software (really just a single php script) that collects cardholder information and stores it in a MySQL database.  Obviously we're taking every precaution with security (Firewall, Anti-Virus, SELinux, restrictive access to the machines), but we're trying to understand what steps we need to take next before taking it live.

As the client is a Level 4 Merchant (no actual transactions, just storage of cardholder information), what scans do we need to go out and find?

Obviously we'll need to have the server/IP scanned, but what about the php script collecting the data?

Comment: I have no experience with PCI, but some general PHP/SQL advice: Sanitize all input, escape all output, and make sure any error messages don't provide any information about what's going on server-side.

Comment: I completely agree with tjmoore1993. However, if you insist.. give VISA a call. Asking people on the internet is definitely the incorrect approach to a highly sensitive issue. VISA will outline the process extremely thoroughly. There are a ton of software as well as physical security precautions to consider. It basically is just not worth the investment to be able to store cardholder information.

Comment: Apparently tjmoore1993's comment was deleted >:(

Comment: Is PCI compliance only for storage of credit card information?  I was under the impression is was required for all transfer - i.e. through a service like Google Checkout as well.

Comment: @jwir3, it is only for credit card information.  Of course, other places may want you to be PCI compliant anyway.  PCI = "Payment Card Industry"

Comment: @Brad: You mean it's only if you want to actually store them on a system controlled by you? I'm sorry, I'm still not sure exactly what's meant here - or is it simply a standard for interfacing with another client/provider ('client' in the business sense here) that would cause you to go this route?

Comment: PCI compliance is simply a security certification that shows you have made some common-sense best practices for maintaining secure credit card transaction information.  If you process credit cards, you are required to be PCI compliant.  It doesn't have anything to do with the payment gateway APIs, and actually has nothing to do with code directly.  PCI compliance includes things like no WiFi networks, not storing the card number, audits (at certain levels), etc.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for being patient and explaining.  :)

Answer (score 4):

The fact that your client isn't actually performing transactions doesn't impact their compliance obligation as PCI/DSS applies just as much to card data storage as it does to transaction processing, infact if they are classifiable as a "Service Provider" there are additions obligations.

Depending on your relationship with your client and how you classify your software (a service/off the shelf product etc) you may also have additional obligations under [PA-DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php?association=PA-DSS) which is geared at the developers of payment (incl just storage) software, and can get pretty hardcore if your selling something designed to be PCI compliant.

If you look through a copy of [V2](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php) of the spec all the requirements are listed, 6.6 explains what you need to do with public facing web applications ("independent" code review or application firewalling) for example.